# Installing a deadbolt on a door with a circular hole for the deadbolt location?

Tags: doors, deadbolt

I recently installed two MasterCraft doors from Menards.  It has two holes in the door.  One for the knob and another for the deadbolt.  If you look at the edge of the door both holes are circular where the bolts will hit the strike plate.

I was able to get the door knob installed without issue because the door knob had the option to slip a circular head over the end.  The deadbolt on the other hand does not have this option.  It has a square/rectangle and that is it, while my door has a circular hole.  I went and looked at the hardware store and all the deadbolts looked to have this rectangle insert for the door and none had a circular insert.

Guessing someone has ran into this before do you just take a chisel to it to create an area for a rectangular insert?  I kind of feel like I shouldn't need to do this on a new door.  Maybe I am missing something.

[image]

What I am talking about specifically are the holes on the edge of the door as seen in picture above.  As you can see there is a circular and rectangle insert in this door.  My door only has a circular insert for both deadbolt and door knob.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is an advantage that your door actually comes with the door pre-drilled. In the cases where the door is not pre-drilled then it is necessary to do the whole schmoo of drilling these holes in the proper locations. Included with that is the job of fitting the lockset edge plates into the properly crafted depression so that the plate is flush or ever so slightly recessed from the edge surface of the door.

You will simply have to use a good sharp chisel and some careful craftsmanship to make the necessary depression for the edge plate. Here are pictures of what the process would look like.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Nice pictures, figured that was the case.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a deadbolt?  Try putting it in.  Although the bolt is rectangular, it is slightly smaller than the one inch hole so it should fit just fine.  The facing which guides the bolt screws into the edge of the door to hold it stable.  It is possible some chiseling will be needed to make the bolt's facing flush with the door.

Comment: Yep, got a deadbolt.  Problem is due to lacking rectangle insert, it is not flush with the door.  Guessing will need to do some chiseling.  I was partially questioning if there is a deadbolt out there that has a circular mount rather than rectangular because I have been to several stores and haven't seen a single one.